# Doing forecasting on future use time having only usage data

Tags: python, machine-learning, iot, prediction, facebook-prophet

I have to do a prediction on the future usage of an iOt device.
I should use Prophet, but i have seen that it does not do what i need. I try to explain myself:

This is the data i have gathered from the iot device i am making:

```
0  2023-09-18 11:15:47.206247   
1  2023-09-18 11:20:59.406388                     
2  2023-09-18 12:52:47.759097                     
3  2023-09-18 17:10:48.486721                    
4  2023-09-18 17:33:15.064502                
5  2023-09-18 21:59:59.867891                   
6  2023-09-19 03:02:42.627580                     
7  2023-09-19 03:55:44.442624                     
8  2023-09-19 03:58:08.154117      
9  2023-09-19 06:03:17.807034    
10 2023-09-19 09:25:14.131301
```

each record is a time of interaction with the device. I would like to do some forecasting on future usage, but i have no idea on what to do.
I need to use prophet.
Right now the only thing it does is telling me that every hour it will be used.

So, how can i forecast future date of usage?

I tried to use prophet giving it the data it needs, but maybe i am not undestanding how to use it properly.
Here is the code i used:

```
tmp = []
for elem in result[0].records:
    tmp.append([elem.row[4].replace(tzinfo=None), elem.row[5]])
# converting results in a df
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["ds","y"])
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)
# making prediction 
m = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.01).fit(df)
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=20, freq = 'H')
forecast = model.predict(future)
```

I could not find a way to make prophet generate the ds column since that's what i need to predict: when the device will be used again!